# Identify large lines on image

Tags: c++, opencv

I have images that consist of vegetation disponsed in lines (may or may not be straight lines).

I need to implement an algorithm that identifies those lines and produces a binary mask image tagging the vegetation pixels. This mask can whether be a dense mask (flagging all the identified vegetation pixels) or skeleton mask (1-pixel wide lines identifying the center of the vegetation lanes).

Here is an example of input images:

[image: Image 1]

And here is one of the possible expected outputs:

[image: Example output]

So far, I've tried the following approaches which result in the following problems:

- Canny edge detector: yields lots of false positives due to shadows
- Image threshold: yields false positives due to ground vegetation.

Anyone has more ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Post your code and result.

Answer (score 3):

If working in RGB color space does not help you, try a different one. For the particular image given, I used the HSV color space.

#### 1. HSV image:

```
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
cv2.imshow('hsv.jpg', hsv)
```

[image]

#### 2. Extracting the *saturation* channel yields this:

```
saturation_channel = hsv[:,:,1]
cv2.imshow('saturation_channel.jpg', saturation_channel)
```

[image]

#### 3. Applying an adaptive threshold on this image yields the following:

```
median = np.median(saturation_channel)
std = np.std(saturation_channel)

ret,thresh1 = cv2.threshold(saturation_channel, int(median - (1.05 * std)), 255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
cv2.imwrite('thresh1.jpg', thresh1)
```

[image]

#### 4. Now you can apply some morphological operations and mask it with the original image

**NOTE:** *You can also convert the image to LAB color space and visualize the different channels.*

The same image in LAB color space:

[image]

Comment: "(I have the code snippet in python)." Even though the OP is using C++, python is readable enough for the snippet to probably be useful to the OP, no? Good answer anyways!

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds indeed I would appreciate looking through the python code

Comment: Can you provide the inputs you passed to adaptiveThreshold? I'm having trouble reproducing your result

Comment: I actually found out that this algorithm is only identifying the shadows... do you confirm?
Just do this:
`Mat display; srcImage.copyTo(display, mask); imshow("Output", display);`

Comment: the shadows are the most prominent color in the HSV space, so I decided to go with it. Considering vegetation, there is some vegetation apart from those along the line. This makes capturing vegetation along the line alone difficult.

Comment: @manatttta I have updated the answer. Feel free to ask anything unclear

Comment: @JeruLuke do you confirm that the positive lanes are relative to the shadows?

Answer (score 0):

You can blur the image before applying Canny and then remove Canny noise by calculating best threshold. After that you can use `HoughLinesP` or your method of choice to detect the lines.

```
cv::Mat src=imread("image.png",-1),dst;

cv::GaussianBlur(src, dst, Size(3,3), 1.0); //blur the source image

cv::cvtColor(dst,dst,cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY); //convert to gray

cv::Scalar m = cv::mean(dst); //calculate mean

//Calculate lower and upper threshold based on mean
double sigma = 0.33;
double lower_thresh = int(std::max((double)0, ((1.0 - sigma) * m[0])));
double upper_thresh = int(std::min((double)255, ((1.0 + sigma) * m[0])));

cv::Canny(dst, dst, lower_thresh, upper_thresh, 3); //apply canny
```

**Blurred image:**

[image: Blurred image]

**Canny:**

[image: Canny]

Comment: I tried this approach. the problem is that this depends a lot on shadows, which may or may not be there...

Comment: @manatttta Can you post an image without shadows? Also JeruLuke gives a great solution. You can certainly try that.